# John Papa Style Guide Checker just like pypi pep8

Tags: angularjs, abstract-syntax-tree, context-free-grammar

Hi I am going through [John Papa's Angular 1 Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1#style-y033). We want to build an automated system to verify that all Angular code pushed by freelancers at our organization complies with the styleguide. Is there any tool out there that can do this for js code, just like how pypi's pep8 does this for python code and the PEP8 Style Guide? Or, do we have to build one from scratch?

If we have to build it from scratch, we would build the checker in Python. Would one use Context Free Grammars (CFGs) -- i.e. NLTK? Or, would one use a python AST Parser to parse and check the js static files?

Comment: You don't want to build parsers and flow analyzers from scratch.  See my essay on Life After Parsing via my bio.

Comment: @GovindaDasu Linter is the way to go. JP and PEP8 style guides are apples and oranges. You physically can't make the machine to verify *all* of JPSG rules in reasonable way. And to be honest, some of them aren't good enough to be strictly followed, JPSG is pretty much glorified and opinionated for no good reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In John papa Angular Style Guide, **there is a chapter answering this question**. He explain all about [22.jshint](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#js-hint) and [23.jscs](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#jscs).
He also provide config files to set them up :)

You can then create a task which will scan your js files and checkup errors regarding those rules. Using pull request pattern, you just refuse any request which does not respect synthaxic rules.

> **FYI** : JSHint is not deprecated and will be slowly replace by [eslint](http://eslint.org/).

Comment: That's linting. But I'm saying for things like -- making sure the entire codebase file names and file structures are johnpapa compliant, making sure there is 1 file per controller, making sure all John papa rules are followed. Does the jshint/jshint make sure ALL JOHN PAPA RULES are followed?